# Ignore NaN's in an (w + x + y)/z situation

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I'm trying to make a little program to do GPA (practice, help me learn some more things), but I've hit a wall.
What I have is something like this

```
    var s1 = blah
    var s2 = blah
```

and so on (to s7) , and then

```
    var GPAresult = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7)/7
```

Which will get the GPA for that semester, this works fine, unless I put in my option of "Study Hall" or "Dropped" in the dropdown list I have to get the variables. These two options return a value of "Null", which is then converted to NaN once sent through the code above, botching the entire thing

So what I need help making is something that would discard the options that default to NaN, and then divide by the legal values, kind of like :

```
    var GPAresult = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7) / legalints
```

I can get the NaN to return a zero, I just need help with counting them and subtracting them from the devisor

Comment: `s1 = isNaN(s1) ? 0 : s1;` etc.

Comment: Using variables with names like `fooX`, where `X` is an increasing number, is a very strong indicator that you should be using an **array** instead. Arrays can be easily *filtered* for non-`NaN` values. For example: `var values = [....].filter(function(s) { return !isNaN(x); });`. Then use `values` to compute the average.

Comment: Write a function that returns `0` if its argument is `NaN` and the argument otherwise.

Comment: I don't think any of the `s` variables are `NaN`s. Seems to me like your variables are `null` and then when used with the addition operator the result becomes `NaN`. So you'll have to check for `null`s not `NaN`s.

Comment: So is s7 undefined/null/something else??? Can change the logic that only adds the last one if it is study hall. `var total = s1 + ...+ s6; var clsCount = 6; if (!sh) { total += s7; clsCount++; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use an array instead of multiple variables, so you can perform certain operations. Example:

```
// Remove from the array all the items that aren't numbers
var numbers = [bla, bla, bla].filter(Number.isInteger);

// Sum all the numbers and store the result in the "sum" variable
var sum = numbers.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});

// Perform the operation
var GPA = sum / numbers.length;
```

- Array [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)
- Array.prototype.filter [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- Array.prototype.reduce [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

**NOTE**
This solution is based on the assumption that you want to subtract invalid numbers from the devisor as you stated on the question.

Comment: `filter(Number)` is really bad code: firstly, it filters out zeros, which is not what the OP wants; and secondly, even if the OP didn't care about the behavior of zeros, the code doesn't mean what it looks it means (and what the comment says it means!), which is always dangerous. Please, leave the "clever" hacks at home.

Comment: @ruakh thanks for the explanation. I've updated the question to address that issue.

However, I'd kindly suggest you to be less rude, we are all learning here.

Comment: Thank you, it ended up working perfectly (I'm not really used to what you can use arrays for, so again thank you for this)

Comment: @user3803026 no problem mate! glad to hear that :)

Comment: @roperzh: Sorry for my rudeness. Thanks for fixing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<strike>var GPAresult = ((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7) / legalints) || 0;</strike>

```
var GPAresult = ((s1 || 0) + (s2 || 0) + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7) / legalints;
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants. That will return `0` if *any* value is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

In the hope to be useful:

```
var s1 = "2";
var s2 = "3";
var s3 = "Study Hall";
var s4 = "4";
var s5 = "Dropped";
var s6 = "5";
var s7 = "6";

var legalints = 0;
var sum = 0;

for(var i= 0;i< 7;i++){
  // variable construction does work for global variables only!
  // please consider useing an array or better: read the results in this
  // loop directly instead of into individual single variables
  var point = parseInt(window["s" + (i+1)]);
  if(!isNaN(point)){
    legalints++;
    sum += parseInt(point);
  }
}

var result = sum / legalints;
```

Checks& balances omitted, as always.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle showing what you are wanting i believe, http://jsfiddle.net/4y5d6waL/

I commented the code in the fiddle, but here it is as well:

```
var s1 = 2;
var s2 = 3;
var s3 = 'bah';

// set 'GPAResult' to what the value the function returns, could take s4, s5, etc. as needed
var GPAResult = GPA(s1, s2, s3);

// Our function (note, it doesn't require any arguemnt)
function GPA(){
    // set the number of classes and the current GradePoints to 0, which is what will return if none of the variables entered are numbers
    var numberOfClasses = 0;
    var GradePoints = 0;

    // because we don't specify how many parameters, we are just itereating through every parameter that we give it
    for (var i in arguments) {

        // then, if the parameter isn't a string, such as 'StudyHall', we will add the value to our GPA variable, and step the numberOfClasses by 1
        if(typeof arguments[i] != 'string'){
            GradePoints += arguments[i];

            numberOfClasses++;
        }
    }

    // After iterating through every parameter entered, divides the GradePoints by the numberOfClasses, giving you the Grade Point Average 
    return GradePoints/numberOfClasses;
}

alert(GPAResult)
```